# Position independent lib in assembly (AT&T syntax)

Tags: linux, assembly, att

I'm implementing a compatibility library that should redirect certain function calls to a differently named function, typically in glibc.

This is what I do:

```
.text

.global compat_function
.extern glibc_function_different_name
compat_function:
    jmp glibc_function_different_name
```

The problem is that is isn't a position independent code and the linker refuses to link a library. I know I need to get GOT involved, but have now idea how (in AT&T asm syntax).

Thanks!

Comment: how is it refusing to link to the library? what error message are you receiving?